# Hide robot model in rviz

Tags: ros, rviz, nao, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've used moveit setup assistant to generate the config files for the Nao robot. I'm then using rviz to visualize joint trajectories. The problem is that the trajectories show up semi-transparent whereas the static robot model that's present when I launch rviz is solid. This makes visualizing a bit annoying.

Is there any way to hide the solid model that shows up when I launch rviz?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222242/hide-robot-model-in-rviz/) by [Ali250](https://answers.ros.org/users/24947/ali250/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2015-12-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fredylucas](https://answers.ros.org/users/25070/fredylucas/) on 2015-12-09**:
I think you must to test the options at left hand on Rviz. There you can fix what you want to see in your environment, and saving the configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be able to simply un-check the 'Visual Enabled' check box under your 'RobotModel' status in the 'Displays' pane on the left side of the screen. See this link for more info:http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/RobotModel

---

Originally posted by [mkhansen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25277/mkhansen/) with karma: 156 on 2015-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0